# Im trying to make a custom alarm android app but alarm not setting

Tags: java, android, firebase

when I hit the submit button on the current activity(dbdisplay), it should switch to the alarmset activity but only when alarmmanager is not null. the other day when I was working on it it would switch from dbdisplay to alarmset but not set an alarm and now it wont even change to the alarmset activity but nothing was changed since i last worked on it. logcat is not giving me any errors, building and cleaning the app didnt work. I'm using google firebase to get the travel time then adding an extra hour then set it as an alarm.  This was all done on the android studio IDE.

TLDR: press button calculate alarm based on start and end point, change activity to confirm the alarm is set and alarm not being set. sorry for weird format.

[Heres a pastebin of all the relevant code](https://pastebin.com/q0Yx0Jag)

```
public void onTravelTimeReceived(String travelTime) {

    long arrivalTime = calculateArrivalTime(travelTime);
    long alarmTime = arrivalTime + (1 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
    ;

    if (alarmManager != null) {
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime, pendingIntent);


        Intent intent = new Intent(dbdisplay.this, alarmset.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }else{
        Intent intent = new Intent(dbdisplay.this, settings.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

heres the function to change activitys when an alarm has been set full code in the pastebin.

I was expecting that once the user presses the confirm button on dbdisplay, an alarm will be set based on the travel time from point a to point b via public transit. the alarm should be using the default clock app on the android device. I have tried to clean and rebuild the app, check the manifest and made sure that the firebase package was added correctly.

Comment: Can you please explain how is this question related to Firebase?

Comment: Well when reading up on how to do the app I was directed a few times to add firebase to it so I assumed that it was important. I never really did any heaving programming especially in app development.